# How to use an object in 2 different methods

Tags: objective-c

So I have an object and I want the object to be able to use in 2 different methods.  Is it possible?  If not, is there any work arounds for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course.  Objects live in dynamic memory and are pointed to by pointers.  So long as you have a reference (the pointer) to an object you can access it from wherever you want.

```
NSObject *theReference = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

After this call, and where theReference is in scope, you will have access to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. An object can be used in 2 different methods.